# What Spring projects are libraries (not framework-oriented)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, libraries, apache-commons

I do not wish to use Spring annotations or xml or any declarative, non-compile-time-safe code or anything that relies on reflection. However, I'm guessing Spring does have traditional libraries (like Apache Commons libraries) that you can call from your code rather than your annotated code getting called by the framework.

What Spring projects are libraries? I'm assuming some of them are.

Comment: How this doesn't fall under Stack Overflow according to the moderators beggars belief. Why have all those Spring tags if Spring questions aren't on topic?!

Comment: The core of Spring is the Spring Framework. Which is uses reflection, annotations etc without remorse. Using spring as a library completely misses the point. 

You could use, say JdbcTemplates with the correct dependency but why?

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to post as an answer so I can give you credit. As for why use library-style, here's why: http://tom.lokhorst.eu/2010/09/why-libraries-are-better-than-frameworks . I'm sure Spring has done some great work that can be leveraged by those of us who don't want to be sucked into the indirection hell, and I thought I'd read somewhere that it does provide library consumption. Maybe I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of Spring is the Spring Framework. Which is uses reflection, annotations etc without remorse. Using spring as a library completely misses the point. You could use, say JdbcTemplates with the correct dependency but why?

If you *do* use Spring as a Library bare in mind you are only getting tiny bits of functionality, most of which is just bootstrap code you avoid writing. Spring is designed to be used within it's framework and built upon. Some do use libraries such as Apache Commons. Using Spring Framework as a library however does just complicate your own project and people would probably ask - "why".

Comment: "Reflection without remorse" gives developers the following: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/101217/70009

Comment: The developers aren't exposed to the internal workings of how spring uses reflection. They don't have to

Comment: ...that is true when, and only when, everything works :)